# Index Match Only Returning First Value - Need Sum

Tags: excel

I've tried searching and have found nothing that helps me with this.

I have a sheet that should display a sum of all amounts matching the corresponding date (Summary Sheet). In another sheet I have all of the data (Data Sheet).

Summary Sheet (wrong numbers, it's only showing the first number it matches):

```
  |    A     |  B 
--|----------|------
1 | Feb 2017 | 40
2 | Mar 2017 | 84.75
```

Data Sheet:

```
   |       C        |   D
---|----------------|-------
 1 | date_effective | amount
 2 | 2/6/2017 0:00  | 40
 3 | 2/6/2017 0:00  | -40
 4 | 2/6/2017 0:00  | 40
 5 | 2/6/2017 0:00  | -40
 6 | 2/6/2017 0:00  | 20
 7 | 2/6/2017 0:00  | -20
 8 | 2/6/2017 0:00  | 20
 9 | 2/6/2017 0:00  | -20
10 | 2/6/2017 0:00  | 240
11 | 2/6/2017 0:00  | -240
12 | 3/16/2017 0:00 | 84.75
13 | 3/16/2017 0:00 | 20
```

What the summary sheet SHOULD look like:

```
  |    A     |  B 
--|----------|-------
1 | Feb 2017 | 0
2 | Mar 2017 | 104.75
```

This is my formula in Summary Sheet B1,

```
=IF(ISNA(INDEX(Table_Query_from_data[amount],MATCH(TEXT(A1,"mmyy"),TEXT(Table_Query_from_data[date_effective],"mmyy"),0))),"",INDEX(Table_Query_from_data[amount],MATCH(TEXT(A1,"mmyy"),TEXT(Table_Query_from_data[date_effective],"mmyy"),0)))
```

Comment: look at sumifs.

Comment: You don't want Index/Match, you want the [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`SUMIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) function and considering that your column "A" the data type is **Date** (i.e 02/01/2017 in `A1`), you could solve using this formula:

```
=SUMIFS(Table[amount],
        Table[date_effective], ">="&A1,
        Table[date_effective], "<="&DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,1)-1)
```

Comment: I abbreviated `Table_Query_from_data` to `Table` to better clear reading.

Comment: `=SUMIFS(Table[amount], Table[date_effective], ">="&A1, Table[date_effective], "<"&DATE(YEAR(A1), MONTH(A1)+1, 1)-1)` works for A1, but not for A2 and up. My data for March was a snippet - the real data should sum to `2052.85` but the formula returns `1527.4`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see why it works for A1 but not for A2. I've tested and works.

Comment: I figured it out. The `"<"` needed to be `"<="`.

Comment: Are you sure? Because, using `"<="` it will be considering "03/01/2017" to "Feb 2017" too.

Comment: In my spreadsheet it works perfectly as intended with `"<="`. I've manually triple-checked the sums myself vs the formula and it works. The `DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,1)-1)` is returning the last day of the month so if I don't add the `=` it only counts up to the second last day of the month (which for March was `1527.4` instead of the `2052.85`, as pointed out earlier).

Comment: My mistake, you are right. Either `"<="&DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,1)-1` or `"<"&DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,1)`.